# HTTP Errors When Using POST Methods

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-blazor

I can't quite seem to figure out how to call HTTP POST functions from my Blazor WASM project hosted with ASP.NET. I am having trouble finding any examples of using POST methods past .NET 6 likely because it's so new. I've tried setting content-headers to JSON and many different ways of retrieving the request body from the actual controller function, but I just get 500, 415, and 400 errors. I've also tried not using model binding the the controller function, but to no avail. I do not believe this is the issue though, as using the [ApiController] attribute infers proper model binding as far as I know. I can only imagine the issue stems from the HTTP call.

The service that calls the method:

```
public async Task CreateUser(User user)
{
    await _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("users", user);
}
```

The controller function:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task PostUser(User user)
{
    _context.Users.Add(user);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

The given from the above code is just a simple 400 error.

Also, I've added a test user into the database manually, and I'm able to retrieve it without any issues.

Comment: Did you set the base URL of the HttpClient you are using to the base URl of your api ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code from one of my demo projects showing API calls to get WeatherForecast records.

Here's the Web Assembly project DataBroker:

```cs
public class WeatherForecastAPIDataBroker : IWeatherForecastDataBroker
{
    private readonly HttpClient? httpClient;

    public WeatherForecastAPIDataBroker(HttpClient httpClient)
        => this.httpClient = httpClient!;

    public async ValueTask<bool> AddForecastAsync(WeatherForecast record)
    {
        var response = await this.httpClient!.PostAsJsonAsync<WeatherForecast>($"/api/weatherforecast/add", record);
        var result = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<bool>();
        return result;
    }

    public async ValueTask<bool> DeleteForecastAsync(Guid Id)
    {
        var response = await this.httpClient!.PostAsJsonAsync<Guid>($"/api/weatherforecast/delete", Id);
        var result = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<bool>();
        return result;
    }

    public async ValueTask<List<WeatherForecast>> GetWeatherForecastsAsync()
    {
        var list = await this.httpClient!.GetFromJsonAsync<List<WeatherForecast>>($"/api/weatherforecast/list");
        return list!;
    }
}
```

And here's the controller it's calling:

```cs
namespace Blazr.Demo.Controllers;

[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    private IWeatherForecastDataBroker weatherForecastDataBroker;

    public WeatherForecastController(IWeatherForecastDataBroker weatherForecastDataBroker)
        => this.weatherForecastDataBroker = weatherForecastDataBroker;

    [Route("/api/weatherforecast/list")]
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<List<WeatherForecast>> GetForecastAsync()
        => await weatherForecastDataBroker.GetWeatherForecastsAsync();

    [Route("/api/weatherforecast/add")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<bool> AddRecordAsync([FromBody] WeatherForecast record)
        => await weatherForecastDataBroker.AddForecastAsync(record);

    [Route("/api/weatherforecast/delete")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<bool> DeleteRecordAsync([FromBody] Guid Id)
        => await weatherForecastDataBroker.DeleteForecastAsync(Id);
}
```

The Repo for the Demo Project [Blazor.Demo](https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazr.Demo)

[Controller Code](https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazr.Demo/blob/master/Blazr.Demo.Controllers/Controllers/WeatherForecastController.cs)
[Data Broker Code](https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazr.Demo/blob/master/Blazr.Demo.Data/DataBrokers/WeatherForecastAPIDataBroker.cs)